# Get url image position android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-glide

I'm loading array of images from server into `RecyclewView` using glide library. 
I have an activity called `ImagePreviewActivity` which I want image from thumbnail to appear to when clicked.
When an item or image is clicked I want to load that image from thumbnail into another activity. How do I achieve that?

**GalleryAdapter.java**

```
  public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Album> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Activity activity;
    public GalleryAdapter(ArrayList<Album> arrayList, Context context) {
this.arrayList = arrayList;
activity = (Activity) context;;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.Thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ImagePreviewActivity.class);
activity.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
//url path of images 
            String path = Config.img_path + arrayList.get(position).getId()+".jpg";
    Glide.with(activity).load(path).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.error).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        return false;
            }
        }).into(holder.Thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
ImageView Thumbnail;
TextView Title;
String img_path;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            Title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_title);
           img_path = Config.img_path +".jpg";


        }
    }
}
```

**ImageActivityPreview.java**

```
 ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String image_url = intent.getStringExtra("imagerurl");
    Glide.with(this).load(image_url).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Could you paste the entire code of your adapter ?

Comment: Done. Please review again

Answer (score 0):

Just send the URL of the clicked image to next activity using

```
intent.putExtra("imgURL",path);
```

method and then load the image using glide in that activity. To the best of my knowledge, if the image is downloaded by glide then it remains in the cache.

Comment: My url contains array of images. How do I get the position of an image clicked